# What is EnvDTE.vsCMTypeRef.vsCMTypeRefCodeType for?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, envdte

`EnvDTE.vsCMTypeRef` enumeration contains kinds of data type function returns.

Alas, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.vscmtyperef.aspx) documentation contains too short descriptions.

Does anyone know what `vsCMTypeRefCodeType` is for?

Comment: The [`CodeType` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.codetype.aspx) _"represents a class construct in a source file"_, so I assume `vsCMTypeRefCodeType` means a reference type (more specifically: a class), or a `Type` is returned. If you can perhaps explain somewhat more detailed what you are trying to do and what you need this information for, better answers can be given.

Comment: @CodeCaster then why does separate vsCMTypeRefObject exist? I just need to check for primitive type.